# Resources not properly loaded on Oracle BI Web Service

Tags: java, oracle, business-intelligence, oracle-bi

I am trying to create a Java + Maven app that uses the Oracle Business Intelligence (BI) Web Service to render an analysis using HTMLViewService. So far I've been using the GO URL without problems, but I want to migrate to Web Services for security reasons.

I am using Oracle Business Intelligence Product Version 12.2 as BI Server and Tomcat 9.0.34 as webserver.

My problem is that the resources are not properly rended/loaded. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in my implementation.

**TLDR:**
Full code and how to reproduce the problem locally on [GitHub](https://github.com/actunderdc/OBIEE).

Here is the report displayed directly in the BI server:
[image]

And here is the report shown in my application:
[image]

As you can see, the dropdown arrow was not displayed, also the CSS for buttons Refresh, Print, Export was not applied. In the console window I got:
[image]

[image]

Network tab:
[image]

[image]

Application tab:
[image]

It looks like **fcustom.css** file is directly importing 2 css files: **master.css** and **facustom.css**. Also some .png files are missing. The application looks for them directly in the root of our server instead of using the bridge. Why aren't all resources going through the bridge servlet?

I managed to overcome the above problem by manually putting those resources in WebContent folder, but this is a dirty solution and it's still not fully functional. Some analysis still do not render at all, export is giving errors etc. as shown on [GitHub](https://github.com/actunderdc/OBIEE#problems-encountered).

Any help will be highly appreciated!